# Jenkins pipeline job failing due to masking supported pattern error

Tags: jenkins, ssh, pipeline, masking

I am currently running a Jenkins pipeline for an application backend shown below, The credentials stage worked perfectly when used in another frontend pipeline part of the application, however I am running into the error shown immediately after the code block below. I have intentionally changed the default region and obviously the IP address. Assistance will be much appreciated.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "region"
        MY_SECRET = ''
        EC2_INSTANCE_IP = "12.345.678.10"
        PATH = "/usr/apps/backend"
        REPO_URL = ''
    }

    stages {
        stage('Set Environment Variables') {
            steps {
                script {
                    MY_SECRET = credentials('AzureRepoPAT')
                    REPO_URL = "https://${MY_SECRET}@path/to/repository"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Make Directory and Change Permissions') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                branch 'cicd-branch'
            }
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'jenkinskey', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE')
                ]) {
                    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: '']) {
                    sh '''
                        sudo chmod 600 $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE ubuntu@${EC2_INSTANCE_IP} "sudo mkdir -p $PATH && sudo chmod 755 $PATH"
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE ubuntu@${EC2_INSTANCE_IP} "sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu $PATH"
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE ubuntu@${EC2_INSTANCE_IP} "sudo git clone ${REPO_URL} $PATH"
                    '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] maskPasswords
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Dev2_Backend_Pipeline_test-cicd@tmp/durable-a7377478
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // maskPasswords
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```